# Table within a cell - Unable to Expand

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm very new to power Bi/ power query, so apologies if I'm explaining this poorly.

I've got a data source providing a column indicating room numbers, most of the cells are fine but there a few hundred that seem to be tables nested within a cell.

[image]

I'm unable to expand these cells as I would normally, I believe because there is a combination of normal number value cell and then these random cells that include a table with text and number values?

I've googled this for a few days but have come up with no answers.

Splitting the column doesn't seem to work, and results in an error.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to split the column, or else expand the tables for these cells?

Thanks very much all.

Comment: Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks so much Horseyride!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
....
Transform=Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere", {{"Room Number", each if Value.Is(_, type table) then _ else #table({"Item"}, {{_}} ) }} ),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(Transform, "Room Number"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Transform, "Room Number", ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand)
in Expanded
```